# How to fetch data from database using angular js (Codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database, codeigniter

How to fetch data from database using angular js (Codeigniter)
when i'm trying to call function controller, its shows 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

500 error means error occur in your controller due to some data base error occur in model or some syntax error's   occur in your controller in codeigniter  please  check your server side code.

Syntax is

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 
 base_url+'Controllername/functionname/'+parameter})
         .then(function(response) {
          //alert(response.data);
          //console.log(response.data);  
 });
```